# Can’t export Key Container iisCngWasKey with aspnet_regiis

Tags: iis

I’m trying to export my IIS encryption keys before Syspre-ing a server, but I get this error: *“The RSA key container was not found”*.

The command I’m running is:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -px "iisCngWasKey" "C:\tmp\iisCngWasKey.xml" -pri
```

The key container I’m trying to export is iisCngWasKey because in applicationHost.config I have:

```
<add name="TestSite">
    <processModel identityType="SpecificUser" userName="AWS\SERVICE_TESTSITE" password="[enc:IISWASOnlyCngProvider:4candDAWi0qbwE5LmMA10H/cs+2ISMPAFdfslEcTiakzDF15YJbW+4/FPxUq9v/xPWfcx8lXlvEr2dzPtg9t5j+wXohPWgxBfsgDobAuy0KG=:enc]" loadUserProfile="true" idleTimeout="00:00:00" />
</add>
```

And, in the providers section:

```
<add name="IISWASOnlyCngProvider" type="Microsoft.ApplicationHost.CngProtectedConfigurationProvider" description="(WAS Only) Uses Win32 Crypto CNG to encrypt and decrypt" keyContainerName="iisCngWasKey" useMachineContainer="true" />
```

For testing purposes, if I try exporting other key containers running `aspnet_regiis -px "iisWasKey" "C:\tmp\iisWasKey.xml" -pri`, it works. 
The only one that fails to export is the one I need.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the operating system?

Comment: The operating system is Windows Windows Server 2019 Datacenter.

Comment: The cause seems to be that `aspnet_regiis` does not support CNG containers, but only RSA containers. So you cannot use this tool. About which tool/scripts to use, that's another question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Lex Li, the answer then is: CNG containers such as iisCngWasKey cannot be exported with aspnet_regiis.

The workaround I used (not optimal) was changing the default key container by amending IIS_schema.xml, recreating the sites and exporting with:

```
aspnet_regiis -px "iisWasKey" "C:\tmp\iisWasKey.xml" -pri
```

Afte that Sysprep and, in the new cloned servers, importing with:

```
aspnet_regiis -pi "iisWasKey" "C:\tmp\iisWasKey.xml"
iisreset
```